# JasperStudio: Add a String to Multi-select Input Control (java.util.Collection)

Tags: collections, jasper-reports

1. I have a multi-select input control corresponding to the parameter **$P{companyId_0}**.
2. I want to add the string "n/a" to the collection; so I created a variable **$V{nullCompany}**.
3. I created an ArrayList variable **$V{companyList}** to add the string to my parameter collection.

   ```xml
   <!-- PARAMETER: COMPANY COLLECTION -->
   <parameter name="companyId_0" class="java.util.Collection" nestedType="java.lang.String">
     <property name="inputControl" value="true" />
     <parameterDescription>
       <![CDATA[Company ID]]>
     </parameterDescription>
     <defaultValueExpression>
       <![CDATA[java.util.Arrays.asList(new java.lang.String[] {"200","100"})]]>
     </defaultValueExpression>
   </parameter>
   <!--VARIABLE: NULL COMPANY STRING-->
   <variable name="nullCompany" class="java.lang.String" calculation="System">
     <variableExpression>
       <![CDATA["n/a"]]>
     </variableExpression>
   </variable>
   <!--VARIABLE: COMPANY LIST-->
   <variable name="companyList" class="java.util.ArrayList" calculation="System">
     <variableExpression>
       <![CDATA[$P{companyId_0}.add( $V{nullCompany} )]]>
     </variableExpression>
     <initialValueExpression>
       <![CDATA[new ArrayList()]]>
     </initialValueExpression>
   </variable>
   ```
4. Resulting error:

   > Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at
   >   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) at
   >   java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
5. Syntax Attempt #2:

   $P{companyId_0}.add(new String[] "n/a" )

> Error Message #2:
>   Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array
>   initializer

6. Syntax Attempt #3:

   $P{companyId_0}.add(new String[] $V{nullCompany} )

> Error Message #3: 
>   The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

Comment: I can't really understand why your are not initializing the parameter with this value also?

Comment: We need crosstabs to populate for dates even if the client has no data for those dates; to do this, we added a Company "n/a", and added seed data to the database.

The client will not know to select Company "n/a", so I am wanting to append this value to the initialized parameter arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an OR statement in the data filtering, to filter the data by Input Control array OR company "n/a":

```
<queryFilterString>accountingPeriod in (dateStart:dateEnd) and (companyId in companyId_0 or companyId == 'n/a')</queryFilterString>
```